# This code discards bullet points and sub bullet points; I need to keep them and indentations

Tags: python-3.x

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.shared import Pt

def main(filename):
    try:
        src_doc = Document(filename)
        tgt_doc = Document()

        styles = src_doc.styles 
        paragraph_styles = [ s for s in styles if s.type == WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH ]
        # print(paragraph_styles)

        styles = tgt_doc.styles['Normal']
        font = styles.font
        font.name = 'Times'
        font.size = Pt(11)

        for src_paragraph in src_doc.paragraphs:
            tgt_paragraph = tgt_doc.add_paragraph()
            for src_run in src_paragraph.runs:
                print('Run: ', src_run.text)
                tgt_run = tgt_paragraph.add_run(src_run.text)
                if src_run.bold:
                    tgt_run.bold = True
                if src_run.italic:
                    tgt_run.italic = True
                if src_run.underline:
                    tgt_run.underline = True

        tgt_doc.save('../Output/the_target.docx')

    except IOError:
        print('There was an error opening the file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("../Input/Current_File.docx")
```

Should be like this:

1.0 PURPOSE The purpose of this procedure is to ensure all feedback is logged, documented and any resulting complaints are received, evaluated, and reviewed in accordance with 21 CFR Part 820 and ISO 13485.

2.0 SCOPE This procedure applies to all feedback received at Orchid. A complaint represents a form of feedback.

3.0 RESPONSIBILITY

3.1 Quality Management/Regulatory Compliance lead:
    Formally designates individuals to receive, review and
    evaluate complaints that comprise the Complaint 
    Handling Unit (CHU).  Job Descriptions and/or Org 
    Charts may be utilized to designate the CHU per site.

NOT Like This:

PURPOSE The purpose of this procedure is to ensure all feedback is logged, documented and any resulting complaints are received, evaluated, and reviewed in accordance with 21 CFR Part 820 and ISO 13485.

SCOPE This procedure applies to all feedback received at Orchid. A complaint represents a form of feedback.

RESPONSIBILITY Quality Management/Regulatory Compliance lead:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code shows that you only keep paragraph styles :

```
paragraph_styles = [ s for s in styles if s.type == WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH ]
```

I think you should try to keep list styles too, with something like this:

```
paragraph_styles = [ s for s in styles if s.type in (WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH, WD_STYLE_TYPE.LIST ]
```